# Why scapy gives an error after running for some time?

Tags: python, scapy

I am using scapy to send arp packets to my another computer in LAN it runs for sometimes and sends some packets but after that scapy stops with an error.

```
Sent Packets: 28Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
spoof('192.168.43.65', '192.168.43.1')
File "main.py", line 15, in spoof
target_mac = get_mac(target_ip)
File "main.py", line 11, in get_mac
return answered[0][1].hwsrc
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scapy/plist.py", line 118, in __getitem__
return self.res.__getitem__(item)
IndexError: list index out of range


def spoof(target_ip, source_ip):
   target_mac = get_mac(target_ip)
   packet = scapy.ARP(op=2, pdst=target_ip, hwdst=target_mac, psrc=source_ip)
   scapy.send(packet, verbose=False)
```

This is my function I am running it in a while loop infinitely.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Hard to know the source of your problem unless you provide some snippet.

Comment: @MaheryRanaivoson I provided some code.

Comment: Duplicate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61126068/python-arp-spoofer-using-scapy-module